# Did the other teachers know that Hermione had a Time-Turner?

Tags: harry-potter, the-prisoner-of-azkaban

Did the teachers know that Hermione has a Time-Turner? For example, when a Boggart is announced during Professor Lupin’s lesson in *Prisoner of Azkaban*, Hermione is greeted by both boys saying “When did she get here?”. Professor Lupin does not say anything.

Although we now know Professor McGonagall gave her this device, did the other teachers know that she had this in her possession?

Answer (score 5):

**DUMBLEDORE**

> Mysterious thing, time. Powerful.
> And, when meddled with...
> dangerous. Sirius Black is in the
> topmost cell of the Dark Tower.
> (to Hermione)
> You know the laws, Miss Granger.
> You must not be seen. And you
> would, I feel, do well to return
> before this last chime. If not...
> well, the consequences are really
> too ghastly to discuss. Three
> turns should do it, I think. If
> you succeed, more than one
> innocent life may be spared
> tonight.

Comment: This doesn't prove whether the teachers whose classes Hermione was attending knew. Not only is Dumbledore generally not very forthcoming with his knowledge towards others (including the teachers), this scene seems to specifically exist to _surprise_ Hermione that Dumbledore knows, which would actually suggest that no one else does (other than McGonagall of course, who is excluded from "the teachers" in this context). You've proven that _someone_ knew she had a time-turner, but you've not proven that "_the other teachers_" (as per the question) knew she had one.

Answer (score 1):

## Probably not.

Obviously, from Rahul's answer, we know that Dumbledore knew. However, there was no reason other teachers had to know about the Time-Turner. For all they knew, Hermione just walked in after her two friends and there was no reason to be concerned by a simple, "When did she get here?" Of course, we have no indication one way or the other, but I don't believe it would be necessary for the other teachers to know.

Answer (score -1):

Contrary to the other responses I believe they did not based on Hagrids remark that they might have been able to apply for time turners to take his class in their 6th years, to which they respond they were destroyed at the ministry last year. This would imply that teachers other than heads of house and Dumbledore are aware of it. Not to mention they talk to each other about their classes and students obviously and the fact that she is in multiple classes at once would come up.